# URL Doubles In Size On Link Click With Mod_Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I am having the WEIRDEST issue! :( Whenever I click on a click it doubles in size, and I assume it is because of the .htaccess file. First off let me post my .htaccess file to you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^[\w.'@\\\/-]+/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ posts.php?sortby=$1&sorttime=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^[\w.'@\\\/-]+/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ posts.php?sortby=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^[\w.'@\\\/-]+$ posts.php [NC,L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Now before I explain a bit more I would like to say that I am using a localhost (not the issue, other pages work fine). I would also like to tell you the file path to the .htaccess and the posts.php.

`localhost/postin'/categories/{category}/{var1-optional}/{var2-optional}`

Now the {category} part can change, so that is why it is the `[\w.'@\\\/-]+`. That is the part that links it up to the posts.php. OK, now to the problem at hand! Lets say I am on the URL:

```
http://localhost/postin'/categories/coding/popular/today
                                    ^category ^var1 ^var2
```

And from that page I click on a button that takes me to

```
http://localhost/postin'/categories/coding/views/today
```

That url will actually take me to:

```
http://localhost/postin'/categories/coding/popular/localhost/postin'/categories/coding/views/today
```

**So my question is why do links double in size when I click on them?**

*P.S. I have another .htaccess in another folder on my website, and links in there work perfectly fine!*

Comment: I honestly think the issue is in your button, and not in the htaccess, can you post the link in the way it shows in the button? (or how the redirect appears in javascript)

Comment: Sure, and I have tried <a> tags, meta location tags, form submit links, and basically everything. They all do the same thing. I am using the link "localhost/postin'/categories/coding/views/today" for testing.

Comment: I suggest you try adding "http" before the localhost (instead of just localhost), I have a hunch.  like http :// localhost

Comment: As an explanation - linking without a protocol (// or http://), and without a relative path(/), simply adds the path of the link to the current URI.

so going from www.example.com through a link with the `href="foo.com" will lead us to www.example.com/foo.com , the link should be `href="http://foo.com" to really redirect. You could see that from your last URL, you can see that the new URL was appended to the end of the origin

Comment: Hmm very interesting thank you! :) If you make a post out of that I will make it as the best one lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation to the OP's problem :

There was nothing wrong with his .htaccess, only the way his href(or link) was built.

Here's the full explanation

linking without a protocol `(// or http://)`, and without a relative path`(/)`, simply adds the path of the link to the current URI. so going from `www.example.com` through a link with the `href="foo.com"` will lead us to `www.example.com/foo.com` , the link should be `href="http://foo.com"`; to really redirect. You could see that from your last URL, you can see that the new URL was appended to the end of the origin